# What is the source of the Apple logo?

Tags: history, apple

[image: Apple rainbow logo]

What is the source of the Apple logo? I heard that it was a reference to Alan Turing, who died of cyanide poisoning after eating an apple.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131565/discussion-on-question-by-neil-meyer-what-is-the-source-of-the-apple-logo).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[This seemingly well-researched article from a design magazine](https://thedesignest.net/apple-logo-history/) says

> According to Janoff [designer of the logo], the reason for choosing this bitten apple logo is to prevent people from confusing the shape of the apple with some other fruit like cherry or tomato, having a similar form.

It also mentions the byte/bite pun, but says that was just a coincidence.

I've never heard the idea that the logo might be related to the apple found by Turing's bed. It seems extremely unlikely, both because it would be in incredibly poor taste and because (as mentioned in comments) Turing wasn't nearly the celebrity in the 1970s that he is now. The wartime codebreaking at Bletchley Park was only declassified in the mid 70s, and the biography *Alan Turing: The Enigma* wasn't published until 1983, years after the Apple logo was designed.

Incidentally, there's little evidence that he died from eating a poisoned apple. He died of cyanide poisoning, and a partially eaten apple was found by his bed. The apple was never tested for poison, and he could easily have been exposed in some other way ([ref](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-18561092)). I'm not sure anyone would even have known about the poisoned apple story before 1983, regardless.

Comment: Yes, his own mother also did not think he committed suicide. She believed it was just an accidental death.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Mothers aren't always the most reliable sources on these matters, but when you add the fact that he was in good spirits by all accounts, didn't leave a suicide note, and did leave a note listing chores he was planning for a date after his death, it really doesn't look like suicide. The BBC article that I linked suggests that the coroner concluded suicide on the grounds that someone deranged enough to be homosexual would also be deranged enough to snap and kill themself without warning. The whole article is worth reading.

Comment: @benrg: About 90% of suicides leave no note.

Comment: He also had cyanide at his house and regularly conducted experiments with it... so accidental exposure is actually quite plausible.

Comment: We certainly did know about Alan Turing. "Turing machine" was part of the lexicon then.

Comment: How did the Turing award factor into this? He must have been somewhat well known in the mid 70s if they were giving out computer science awards bearing his name.

Comment: Turing was recognised as a distinguished computer science pioneer in the 1970s. But his work at Bletchley wasn't public knowledge, nor was his personal life. It's unlikely that Apple were particularly interested in him.

Comment: @benrg "The BBC article that I linked suggests that the coroner concluded suicide on the grounds that someone deranged enough to be homosexual would also be deranged enough to snap and kill themself without warning." Or that they were covering up a government assassination, by deeming it a suicide. The article you linked says that murder can't be ruled out, either.

Answer (score 34):

According to official sources, the *name* Apple came first.  In an interview with Steve Jobs and Steve Wozniak, recorded to an internal Apple video, it is explained that the name just… appeared.  The recording is kept in an archive at Stanford; while the video itself is not available publicly, Terence Chea of the Associated Press [transcribes it](https://phys.org/news/2011-12-stanford-archives-window-apple.html) as follows:

> WOZNIAK: I remember driving down Highway 85. We’re on the freeway, and Steve mentions, ‘I've got a name: Apple Computer.’ We kept thinking of other alternatives to that name, and we couldn't think of anything better.
>
> JOBS: And also remember that I worked at Atari, and it got us ahead of Atari in the phonebook.

Many sources take this as indication that appearing before Atari was the primary motivation for the name, but this is only weakly implied above.

So the initial impulse to associate apples with computing wasn’t through Turing.  And while this connection may have appeared later, this is also pretty doubtful, as [@benrg’s answer](/a/21765/15334) explains.

Comment: I don't think anybody sane would keep a written reference of where logo came from because it can later be used to due the company for using somebody else's IP. Especially when logos are designed the competition is being investigated. So designers will be careful not to keep record of where ideas came from.

Comment: @akostadinov "fear of being sued" sounds like more of a reason to keep very good records of where the idea came from, so that you can prove that you own the rights to it.

Comment: @akostadinov You think someone could have copyrighted the apple that was found next to Turing?

Comment: @user3840170, I don't know anything. If it is known that idea came from something, I guess it is a potential lawsuit danger. Logos and other official names are cleared by lawyers but no record is kept as to how was that done and in case of rejection, no explanation is given. This is what I have observed.

Answer (score 13):

> That apple by his deathbed has become the most famous in science since
> Isaac Newton’s windfall, with claims that Turing poisoned it so he
> could mimic the one in his favourite fairy-tale, Disney’s Snow White,
> and – repeatedly – that it inspired Apple’s famous once-bitten logo.
>
> Although writer/actor/presenter/technophile Stephen Fry says that when
> he asked Apple founder Steve Jobs if the story is true, Jobs replied:
> "God we wish it were. It's just a coincidence."
>
> Source: [bbc.com](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20120620-the-turing-test-of-time)

Here you can see the clip in its context:

https://youtu.be/A1Ds2eq1E5o?t=560

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question about the origin of the Apple logo, though it does clarify the context of OP's mistaken claim.

Comment: @V2Blast https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/duty_calls.png

Answer (score 6):

It probably has something to do with the fact that [Jobs was at one point on a diet of almost nothing but apples](https://www.businessinsider.com/steve-jobs-diet-food-extreme-fasting-habits-2019-7?r=US&IR=T#after-reading-lapps-book-which-endorsed-vegetarianism-jobs-said-he-would-go-on-extreme-diets-including-purges-and-fasts-and-would-eat-just-one-or-two-foods-for-weeks-like-apples-or-carrots-2). He was spending his college time looking in on all sorts of courses from philosophy to calligraphy. It was also the time of "dropping out" of mainstream society and questioning everything about diet, drugs, people living in groups, relationships, etc. The health food shops we take for granted today, many of these started as commune co-ops back then.

Jobs eventually had to give up on the apples diet as he was showing signs of ill-health from it. But I guess he retained a fondness for the apple and its form may have occupied a prominent place in his mind.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the cover of the [*Apple 1 Operation Manual*](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_appleapple_1775046/), I'm going to go with "Isaac Newton."

[image]